# Feed for updating shipping price fails with No child element is expected at this point

Tags: xml, amazon-mws

IM trying to update the shipping cost for my product. This is the feed that I submit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_GAATUSALES_1356361</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Override</MessageType>
    <Message> 
        <MessageID>1</MessageID> 
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType> 
        <Override> 
            <SKU>112629</SKU> 
            <ShippingOverride> 
                <ShipAmount currency="USD">120.00</ShipAmount> 
                <IsShippingRestricted>false</IsShippingRestricted>
            </ShippingOverride> 
        </Override> 
    </Message> 
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

This is the response that I receive from amazon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_GAATUSALES_1356361</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>11074252872</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>0</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>1</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>5000</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>XML Parsing Error at Line 16, Column 30: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'IsShippingRestricted'. No child element is expected at this point..</ResultDescription>
            </Result>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Any ideas what I do wrong? I use Amazon Scratchbook for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML does not validate.

`ShippingOverride` is defined in [`Override.xsd`](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Override.xsd) as one of the following:

```
<ShippingOverride>
  <ShipOption>...</ShipOption>
  <IsShippingRestricted>...</IsShippingRestricted>
</ShippingOverride>
```

or

```
<ShippingOverride>
  <ShipOption>...</ShipOption>
  <Type>...</Type>
  <ShipAmount currency="...">...</ShipAmount> 
</ShippingOverride>
```

where

- `ShipOption` is not restricted by the schema, but seems have a [list of valid values](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=11560#100043)
- `IsShippingRestricted` is either `true` or `false`
- `Type` is either `Additive` or `Exclusive`
- `ShipAmount` needs a currency ISO-code (e.g. `USD` or `GBP`) and a numeric value.

Please note that the [currency ISO code seems to be cosmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776728/amazon-mws-api-currency).