# Amazon MWS "Flat File Price and Quantity Update Feed"

Tags: amazon-mws

I want to use the feed api to submit the stock and price of my products to Amazon Marketplaces in EU.
Using the FeedType `_POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA_` with the appropriate CSV seems to work.
Since I have different prices for the marketplaces I was wondering how to set the right currency? Right now it just autoconverts my € prices to GBP.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon MWS seems to ignore whatever currency you supply and use the currency of the marketplace. See this SO question for details:  [Amazon MWS API - Currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776728/amazon-mws-api-currency)