# Amazon MWS listings showing in GBP not EUR

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm sending products to all 5 amazon Europe stores and I always use the Euro (EUR) currency, even to Amazon UK store.

The problem is that when I download the XML with all the sales they are returned in EUR, for all stores except the UK; which is displayed in Great British Pound (GBP).

I have tried searching on Amazon MWS forum but I didn't see anyone who has the same problem or doesn't care about the currency.

Does anyone know how to get Amazon MWS product sales in the EUR currency format for my listings?

Answer (score 1):

Unless things have changed recently, all data sent to and received from the UK store are in GBP. France, Germany, Italy and Spain use EUR. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776728/amazon-mws-api-currency?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually i send my products to all 5 european stores in EUR currency and amazon do the conversion onto GBP so i think they maybe can send the currency back in EUR when i ask to the Webservice

Comment: If they do the conversion from EUR to GBP, then that is a new thing. It didn't use to do this (see linked question). I'm pretty sure though, that the reports on Amazon UK will always be in GBP, and I don't think that'll change any time soon since there is currently no way to specify the currency when requesting a report

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I have this issue too. In Seller Central you can set your home marketplace to .de or whatever which will make EUR your default.

In the finance report, specifically, the bi-weekly payments report everything there will be in EUR.

However, in the reports and orders api, specifically things like fulfilled shipments and orders, etc is going to based on the customer's POV and what they paid. Also, sometimes VAT is taken out of the item price and added in a separate line item and sometimes not. (this is largely do to the from/to shipping countries, and if buyer is a biz customer with their own vat set or exempt, etc)

If you want consistent sales reports, just record your daily set EUR price, and instead just look at the qty sold across marketplaces multiplied by your price. This is what you will be paid on.